# Update value in object array with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of objects and I want to update a value within those objects using the useState hook, but unclear on how to format this and get it working.

```
setCarUnsubscribeList(carUnsubscribeList => (carUnsubscribeList.forEach((car:CarSelections) => {
  car.checked = true;
})));
```

Comment: does it occur any error?

Answer (score 1):

`spread` the original object and change the propert you want

```
setAllChecked(prev => prev.map(car =>({
    ...car,
    checked : true
})))
```

Comment: I use TypeScript and am getting this error, when using this format: 'Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'CarSelections[]''.